# Is there a race between starting and seeing yourself in WinApi's EnumProcesses()?

Tags: windows, winapi, process

I just found this code in the wild:

```
def _scan_for_self(self):
        win32api.Sleep(2000) # sleep to give time for process to be seen in system table.
        basename = self.cmdline.split()[0]
        pids = win32process.EnumProcesses()
        if not pids:
            UserLog.warn("WindowsProcess", "no pids", pids)
        for pid in pids:
            try:
                handle = win32api.OpenProcess(
                    win32con.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | win32con.PROCESS_VM_READ,
                        pywintypes.FALSE, pid)
            except pywintypes.error, err:
                UserLog.warn("WindowsProcess", str(err))
                continue
            try:
                modlist = win32process.EnumProcessModules(handle)
            except pywintypes.error,err:
                UserLog.warn("WindowsProcess",str(err))
                continue
```

This line caught my eye:

```
win32api.Sleep(2000) # sleep to give time for process to be seen in system table.
```

It suggests that if you call `EnumProcesses()` too fast after starting, you won't see yourself. Is there any truth to this?

Answer (score 3):

There is a race, but it's not the race the code tried to protect against.

A successful call to [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) returns only after the kernel object representing the process has been created and enqueued into the kernel's process list. A subsequent call to [`EnumProcesses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses) accesses the same list, and will immediately observe the newly created process object.

That is, unless the process object has since been destroyed. This isn't entirely unusual since processes in Windows are [initialized in-process](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150716-00/?p=45131). The documentation even makes note of that:

> Note that the function returns before the process has finished initialization. If a required DLL cannot be located or fails to initialize, the process is terminated.

What this means is that if a call to `EnumProcesses` immediately following a successful call to `CreateProcess` doesn't observe the newly created process, it does so because it was **late** rather than early. If you are late already then adding a delay will only make you more late.

Which swiftly leads to the *actual* race here: Process IDs uniquely identify processes only for a finite time interval. Once a process object is gone, its ID is up for grabs, and the system will reuse it at some point. The only reliable way to identify a process is by holding a handle to it.

Now it's anyone's guess what the author of `_scan_for_self` was trying to accomplish. As written, the code takes more time to do something that's probably altogether wrong<sup>1</sup> anyway.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Turns out my gut feeling was correct. This is just your average POSIX developer, that, in the process of learning that POSIX is insufficient would rather [call out Microsoft](https://github.com/kdart/pycopia/blob/1446fabaedf8c6bdd4ab1fc3f0ea731e0ef8da9d/QA/pycopia/remote/WindowsServer.py#L151) instead of actually using [an all-around superior API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipes).*

Answer (score 2):

1. The documentation for `EnumProcesses` ([WIn32 API - EnumProcesses function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses)), does **not** mention anything about a delay needed to see the current process in the list it returns.
2. The example from Microsoft how to use `EnumProcess` to enumerate **all** running processes ([Enumerating All Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes)), also does **not** contain any delay before calling `EnumProcesses`.
3. A small test application I created in C++ (see below) always reports that the current process is in the list (**tested on Windows 10**):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

const DWORD MAX_NUM_PROCESSES = 4096;
DWORD aProcesses[MAX_NUM_PROCESSES];

int main(void)
{
    // Get the list of running process Ids:
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    if (!EnumProcesses(aProcesses, MAX_NUM_PROCESSES * sizeof(DWORD), &cbNeeded))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Check if current process is in the list:
    DWORD curProcId = GetCurrentProcessId();
    bool bFoundCurProcId{ false };
    DWORD numProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);
    for (DWORD i=0; i<numProcesses; ++i)
    {
        if (aProcesses[i] == curProcId)
        {
            bFoundCurProcId = true;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "bFoundCurProcId: " << bFoundCurProcId << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Note**: I am aware that the fact that the program reported the expected result does **not** mean that there is no race. Maybe I just couldn't catch it manifest. But trying to run code like that can give you a hint sometimes (especially if the result would have been that there is a race).

The fact that I never had a problem running this test (did it many times), together with the lack of any mention of the need for a delay in Microsoft's documentation make me believe that it is not required.

**My conclusion is that either:**

1. There is a unique issue when using it from python (doubt it).
   **or:**
2. The code you found is doing something unnecessary.

Comment: thanks for checking, this is pretty much what i expected :) btw you should add what OS you tested it on (perhaps it was a problem on Windows XP but not since Vista? or a problem on Windows 7 but not windows 10? etc - i doubt it's relevant, but should add it just in case)

Comment: @hanshenrik thanks - added the info (Windows 10).

Comment: i don't think it makes any significant difference, but you could save a runtime allocation by replacing ```std::vector<DWORD> aProcesses(MAX_NUM_PROCESSES);``` with a global `DWORD aProcesses[MAX_NUM_PROCESSES];` thereby calling EnumProcesses() a tiny bit faster - but all of this is still *much* faster than the equivalent Python code, soo yeah, 99.9% sure it won't make a difference ^^

Comment: Tried it (out of curiousity). Didn't observe any difference.

Comment: BTW - I think that on Windows with MSVC, global arrays are allocated on the heap (not in the data segment). So the usage of a std::vector like in my original code was quite similar. Not sure about that.

Comment: I updated the code anyway to use the global array (for sure it's at least as fast as `std::vector`, maybe marginally faster).

Comment: @wohlstad No, MSVC puts global arrays into data segment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no race.

`EnumProcesses` calls a NT API function that switches to kernel mode to walk the linked list of processes. Your own process has been added to the list before it starts running.